# Route to parent navigator - React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have a stackNavigator nested in another stackNavigator:

```
Parent Navigator:
Index.js
Login.js
Signup.js
Home.js
```

My child navigator is on the signup.js component. Where i have

```
Children Navigator:
Name.js
Email.js
```

When the userRegistration is successful on Email.js Screen I want to navigate to the Home.js screen, but it is in my parent stack. I could take the nested stack out and put those components in the parent stack, however I think it would be helpful if I learned how to route through stacks (especially in the future).

Is it possible to route through stackNavigators in React Native?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. Pass down the root navigation and navigate using it:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Signup: { screen: ({ navigation }) => <SignupStack screenProps={{ rootNavigation: navigation }} /> }
  Home: { screen: HomeStack },
  ...
});
```

then from your Email.js:

```
this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation.navigate('Home')
```

Credits go to [this answer](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/335#issuecomment-285888685)

Comment: this gave me an error in my email.js undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation')..

Comment: do you think I have to add to my constructor or something?

Comment: This is not working with the latest `react-navigation`